# pull artifactory docker image

Tags: docker, artifactory, bintray

I am not able to pull Artifactory docker image using below command

```
docker pull jfrog-docker-reg2.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro:latest
```

It ends up with below error

```
Error response from daemon: invalid registry endpoint https://jfrog-docker-reg2.bintray.io/v0/: unable to ping registry endpoint https://jfrog-docker-reg2.bintray.io/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://jfrog-docker-reg2.bintray.io/v2/: dial tcp 119.81.184.206:443: i/o timeout
 v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://jfrog-docker-reg2.bintray.io/v1/_ping: dial tcp 119.81.184.206:443: i/o timeout. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry jfrog-docker-reg2.bintray.io` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/jfrog-docker-reg2.bintray.io/ca.crt
```

What shall I do here? Why its asking for certificate? and if I access the link of JFrog repo, it asks for username and password. How can I get this image.

I was following official link of Artifactory to do this.https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Running+with+Docker. I searched on net but no solution.

Comment: Can you add some more information such as the host running Docker and Docker version?

Comment: This seems to have been a temporary network issue with the Bintray cloud provider infrastructure in Hong-Kong during the weekend. This should have been resolved.

Comment: host runnig docker is centos 6.7 and docker version is 1.7.1, Isue is still not resolved and i am not able to pull the image.Am i doing anything wron

Comment: @thinkingmonster troubleshooting this will require gathering some more information. can you please contact support@bintray.com for further help. they are aware of the issue and will assist with resolving it

Answer (score 3):

Update 2017: [the documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+with+Docker) now mentions:

```
docker pull docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro:latest
```

See "[`JFrogDev/artifactory-docker-examples` issue 1](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-docker-examples/issues/1#issuecomment-276898561)", in Feb. 2017:

> You should use the `docker.bintray.io` tag.
>   It's simply an alias to `frog-docker-reg2.bintray.io`, so you can't go wrong.